# Html.Actionlink Method in Razor

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have a table in my database which stores events. I am currently on my *Homecontroller's* index view page and I need to post a link to the *edit* method of my *EventsController* which takes in the *ID* of an event and edits it. Can I do this:-

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "~/Controllers/EventsController.cs/Edit", new { id=item.ID })
```

or do I have to write something else to achieve my motive. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", "Events", new { id=item.ID }, null)
```

You can use overload, [`LinkExtensions.ActionLink Method (HtmlHelper, String, String, String, Object, Object)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd504972%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

For more info visit [LinkExtensions.ActionLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink%28v=vs.118%29.aspx)

Comment: @satpal...when I loaded the page and checked the source html...The redirection was to edit method of Home and not to Events/Edit

Answer (score 2):

You can use the code as

```
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "EventsController", new { id=item.ID })
```

There are different overloads available for  "ActionLink", check them out. eg.

http://microsoftmentalist.wordpress.com/2011/09/23/asp-net-mvc-17-html-actionlink-and-html-routelink-helper-methods/

In case you controller is placed in some different location (may be because of area ), you will have to specify it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Link Text", "Edit", "Events", new { id=item.ID })
```

Comment: @idlerboris....when I loaded the page and checked the source html...The redirection was to edit method of Home and not to Events/Edit